# Shared Cluster: Cannot use Secret

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am switching from a `No Isolated Shared` to a `Shared` Cluster.
My Spark Config in the cluster looks like the following:

```
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret {{secrets/keyvault/s}}
fs.azure.account.auth.type OAuth
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/token
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id def
```

In my notebook I am working with the Azure Logging Library an my code looks like the following:

```
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.monitor.ingestion import LogsIngestionClient

#init
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=os.getenv("AZ_TENANT_ID"), client_secret=spark.conf.get("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret"), client_id=spark.conf.get("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id"))
client = LogsIngestionClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=credential, logging_enable=True)
client.upload(....)
```

I always get the following error message:

> Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the
> request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a
> secret added to app

When switching to `No Isolated Shared` it works. How can I run the code with a `Shared` Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Azure Databricks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/compute/configure#--access-modes), the **no isolation shared** cluster configuration uses the root credentials, while the **shared** cluster configuration uses the current user's credentials.

You have to create some credentials for the current user profile in which you are running the notebook and use them for the connection.